# processing independent values from iterating through a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

```
Faultysats=[{'G11': '16 01 13 09 43 50.0000000'},
            {'G11': '16 01 13 09 43 51.0000000'},
            {'G03': '16 01 13 09 43 52.0000000'}]
SATS=['G01', 'G03', 'G04', 'G08', 'G11', 'G19', 'G28', 'G32']
EPOCH='16 01 13 09 43 51.0000000'
```

I have a these lists- faultysats, a list of dictionaries containing varying satellite and epoch times; SATS, a list containing sats; and EPOCH, a time value.
If a satellite from faultysats (e.g'G11') appears in SATS AND its corresponding epoch (eg. '16 01 13 09 43 50.0000000') from faultysats appears in EPOCH, I want to know which index the satellite is at in the SATS list.

Hope that makes sense, im struggling because i dont know how to ascertain varying values in a list of dictionaries. Is there a certain operator that deals with extracting data from a list of sats?

Answer (score 0):

To get a list of the indexes you could use:

```
Faultysats=[{'G11': '16 01 13 09 43 50.0000000'},
            {'G11': '16 01 13 09 43 51.0000000'},
            {'G03': '16 01 13 09 43 52.0000000'}]
SATS=['G01', 'G03', 'G04', 'G08', 'G11', 'G19', 'G28', 'G32']
EPOCH='16 01 13 09 43 51.0000000'

indexes = []

for i in range(0, len(Faultysats)):
    for key in Faultysats[i]:
        if (key in SATS) and (Faultysats[i][key] == EPOCH):
            indexes.append(i)

print(indexes)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

Get first the list of dictionaries's keys whose corresponding `value` is equal to `EPOCH` then get the index of that `key` from `SATS`:

```
>>> Faultysats=[{'G11': '16 01 13 09 43 50.0000000'},
            {'G11': '16 01 13 09 43 51.0000000'},
            {'G03': '16 01 13 09 43 52.0000000'}]
>>> SATS=['G01', 'G03', 'G04', 'G08', 'G11', 'G19', 'G28', 'G32']
>>> EPOCH='16 01 13 09 43 51.0000000'
>>> f = [k for d in Faultysats for k,v in d.items() if EPOCH == v]
>>> indx = [SATS.index(x) for x in f]
>>> 
>>> indx
[4]
```

Answer (score 0):

First, let's get a list of all satellites from `Faultysats` that are in `SATS` and have the `EPOCH` timestamp.

```
sats = [sat for pair in Faultysats for sat, epoch in pair.iteritems() 
        if sat in SATS and epoch == EPOCH]
>>> sats
['G11']
```

Now you can use a dictionary comprehension to provide the index location of each satellite in SATS (assuming there are no duplicates).

```
>>> {s: SATS.index(s) for s in sats}
{'G11': 4}
```